What does "rites" refer to?
Jessica speaks to a Maker Keeper who killed a sandworm by drowning it in water and
extracted the "Water of Life" from it:

Jessica: Listen carefully. Soon a man is going to visit your temple
and he may want you to perform the rites.
Maker Keeper: Reverend Mother, it is forbidden.
Jessica: You question the prophecy?
Maker Keeper: No man will survive.
Jessica: Let him try!

What does "rites" refer to?

The same rites that Jessica had earlier performed. Did you watch the movie till the end? If not, I suggest doing so.

I'm not entirely sure, but I do know you can't make one out of two rongs.

In order to become a full-fledged 'Reverend Mother' (complete with the ability to access the genetic memory of all of the women who have preceded them), a Bene Gesserit will consume the 'water of life', the exhaled fluid from a drowned sandworm.
There's a bunch of ceremony and hoo-ha ("the rites") but the important bit is where they drink the water of life, then use their psychokinetic powers to change the water from a deadly poison into a powerful, but non-deadly drug.
Jessica is explaining that Paul will try to undertake this task, which, under normal circumstances would kill him. A man cannot be a Reverend Mother.
